# The import org.apache cannot be resolved (shopizer root project)

Tags: apache, maven, shopizer

I'm new with shopizer Commerce, i have downloaded the project from github, and run the below maven comands :

mvn clean

mvn insatall

And it built the modules with succes but there are still some problems in the root project like the importaion of "org.apache.commons.lang.Validate" can not be resolved.

I'm using STS and Jdk 1.8

Thanks for any help or suggestions

[As you can see at the picture : The import org.apache cannot be resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV1pP.png)

Comment: It seems that these are not in your classpath. use `mvn:eclispe:eclipse` from your root folder and to enable WTP support, run `mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse`

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm getting erros with mvn eclipse:eclipse like this :  **[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'eclispe' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Ahmed hendah\.m2\repository), spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] ->**                                        NB: I'm sing STS